# How do I mark and label "To-Do"s?

Tags: python, python-2.7, atom-editor, todo

How do I clearly mark and label "To-Do"s directly in my code (using Atom on Mac) for later?

Comment: Write a failing test? In your case 2, the idiomatic exception would be `NotImplementedException`.

Comment: I use #TODO and then use `grep -n` from the command line to list them all out with the line numbers (-n). That is if you're on Linux.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat I've seen and read that post, I've read the on-topic help for that site and have looked at some top questions.  I don't think this question is off-topic for either site and still think it's more on-par with software engineering.  I admit I meant "stackoverflow is more about **technical** problems" where I said 'objective based', that is on me.

Comment: @gnat I don't think it's that poor of a fit for this site. It's an IDE question, which is on topic. I also seem to be missing some context due to deleted comments though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just mark your comments with `# TODO`. Most IDEs have a way of aggregating these comments to a list. Atom is no different, although you'd need to install [a plugin for it](https://atom.io/packages/todo-show).

Comment: Plugin works well! Certain syntax themes also make `TODO` stand out more in Atom, such as "Solarized Dark"

Comment: The syntax highlighting is free though.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't strictly satisfy your requirement of not using comments, but most IDEs support "Todos". Just start a comment with "todo":

```
# TODO: Fix this code!
```

In many IDEs, this will cause the comment to be marked in some bright color (light blue in IntelliJ), and put it into a TODO section so it can be viewed later. This can also affects things like Git commits. I'm warned if I try to commit code that contains a TODO.

Answer (score 2):

I use `input`s with a description of the surrounding code/what needs done, they stop execution to make it obvious something needs done while allowing you to continue.